# Is it possible to add new embedded worker while cluster is running on statefun?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch, flink-statefun

Here is the deal;

I'm dealing with adding new worker (embbeded) to on running the cluster (flink statefun 2.2.1).

As you see the new task manager can be registered to the cluster;

[Screenshot of new deployed taskmanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD3f1.jpg)

But it doesn't initialize (it doesn't deploying sources);

What am I missing here?? (master and workers has to same jar files too? or it should be enough deploying taskmanager with jar file)

Any help would be appreciated,
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Flink supports two different approaches to rescaling: *active* and *reactive*.

*Reactive mode* is new in Flink 1.13 (released just this week), and works as you expected: add (or remove) a task manager, and your application will adjust to the new parallelism. You can [read about elastic scaling and reactive mode in the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/elastic_scaling/).
Reactive mode is currently a work in progress, but might need your needs.

In broad strokes, for *active mode* rescaling you need to:

1. Do a [stop with savepoint](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/cli/#terminating-a-job) to bring down your current job while taking a snapshot of its state.
2. Relaunch with the new parallelism, [using the savepoint as the starting point](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/cli/#starting-a-job-from-a-savepoint).

The exact details depend on how your cluster is deployed.

For a step-by-step tutorial, see [Upgrading & Rescaling a Job](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/try-flink/flink-operations-playground/#upgrading--rescaling-a-job) in the [Flink Operations Playground](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/try-flink/flink-operations-playground/).

---

The above applies to rescaling statefun embedded functions. Being stateless, remote functions can be rescaled more straightforwardly.